# pick two rows value except equals for each row?

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I'm a super noob at sql, therefore its might not clearly explanation what am I ask on title. sorry about that.

I'll explain as much as I can do with a simple example.

Please, look at my table first

```
select * from table board;
```

```
-----------------------------
num | category1 | category2 |
-----------------------------
1   | c         | tutorial
2   | c         | note
3   | c++       | tutorial
4   | c++       | code
-----------------------------
```

I want to pick each category's values list like this

```
select distinct category1 from board;
```

```
category1 
-----------
c
c++


select distinct category2 from board;
```

```
category2 
-------------
code
note
tutorial
```

It's easy I can do that, but its lame I guess.
This query needs to run twice to select each category.

I'm expecting result like

```
category1 | category2 
---------------------
c         | NULL 
c++       | NULL 
NULL      | code 
NULL      | note
NULL      | tutorial
```

And what I tried code is below

```
Select category1 as cat1, category2 as cat2 
FROM board
LEFT JOIN (SELECT distinct category1 FROM blog)tb1
ON cat1 = tb1.category
LEFT JOIN (SELECT distinct category2 FROM blog)tb2
ON cat2 = tb2.category;
```

but its returns

```
category1 | category2 
---------------------
c         | tutorial
c         | note
c++       | tutorial
c++       | code
```

I'm very stuck now.

Is there any way to run the query only once? such as using SubQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `UNION`:

```
select category1, NULL AS category2 from board
UNION 
select NULL, category2 from board;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=8eccae2a8fa65a9ec060728d189cc86a)**

Comment: OMG im so dumb. Thanks for kind reply!!! it's work perfectly!! will accept your question after a 10minuate!